# need help on proof question on matrices MEI FP2

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix M is (n × n). For n=2 and n=3 prove that if the sum of the elements in each row of M is 1, then 1 is an eigenvalue of M.

I know that to find eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, the characteristic equation Ms=xs can be manipulated. However, I am finding trouble with this proof question.

Please be easy on the jargon and keywords- I find them intimidating

Answer (score 2):

If $\;M=(a_{ij})\;$ , then for **any** element $\;x\in \Bbb F=$the definition field, we have

$$M\begin{pmatrix}x\\x\\\ldots\\x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}\\{}\\x\sum_{k=1}a_{2k}\\{}\\\ldots\\{}\\x\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\x\\\ldots\\x\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The above shows that the given vector $\;(x,x,...,x)^t\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;M\;$ with eigenvalue $\;1\;$ , of course...do you know what eigenvectors and eigenvalues are?

Comment: @HakkihanTunbak You're wrong. The above uses the given info, namely: that the sum of each row is $\;1\;$ ....etc.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)=1\times\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$
because $a+b=1$ and $c+d=1$.  The $3\times 3$ (or, indeed, $n\times n$) case works similarly.

Comment: Thanks! Seems really obvious now!

Comment: Looking back on this, a slightly more sophisticated way would be to substitute the two statements to eliminate b and d, and then proceed to solve the characteristic determinant equation of M-{lambda}I = 0, which is a quadratic equation in {lambda}. After some fiddly algebra (or you can even just verify that 1 is a solution by substituting it in) we can obtain {lambda} = 1 as one of the solutions.